# Vulkan: efficient way to update VBO mesh vertices?

Tags: opengl, 3d, vulkan, vertex-buffer-object

I would like to change/add/remove some mesh vertices in existing VBO's (while deforming and remeshing 3D objects) . With OpenGL I would have to reload whole vertex VBO's. I suppose with Vulkan there could be a way to directly access VBO's to only change/add/remove the changed vertex data. Is there some sample code out there demonstrating how this can be achieved? 
Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With OpenGL I would have to reload whole vertex VBO's.

No you wouldn't.  You can use `glBufferSubData`

> I suppose with Vulkan there could be a way to directly access VBO's to only change/add/remove the changed vertex data

If you know the memory layout of the vertex buffer, you can find the offset of the contents you want to change, populate a transfer buffer with the new data and then uss [vkCmdCopyBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkCmdCopyBuffer.html) to copy the data.  The `VkBufferCopy` parameter lets you specify the size as well as the source and destination offsets.  In other words, every call to `vkCmdCopyBuffer` is basically the equivalent of N calls to `glBufferSubData`

To clarify, updating a vertex buffer on Vulkan is almost the same as populating it.  If you're on a desktop architecture where *device local* memory is typically not mappable, then you have to create a transfer buffer that is *host visible*.  You can populate that buffer with a memcpy (or whatever), and then use `vkCmdCopyBuffer` to transfer it to the *device local* memory backed buffer.  If you're on a mobile architecture with unified memory, then *device local* memory is typically also *host visible* and so you can just map it directly and update it with your `memcpy` (or whatever)

Comment: "*If you're on a desktop architecture where device local memory is typically not mappable, then you have to create a transfer buffer that is host visible.*" Even implementations that offer split memory may allow you to use host-visible memory for vertex data. In cases where you're frequently uploading data (like a GUI), this would be a good thing to use.

Comment: Also, synchronization is really important when updating memory.